# bionic: dpkg options does not work using apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, 18.04

The options force-confdef and force-confold that worked fine in 14.04 and 16.04 seems not to work in 18.04 any more.
Neither `apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade -y` nor setting the options in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local or /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg are working.

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local:

```
Dpkg::Options {
  "--force-confdef";
  "--force-confold";
};
```

/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg:

```
force-confdef
force-confold
```

There is always a dialog popping up which makes any kind of automation impossible.
Is there an other way for doing that? Is it a bug?

Comment: What dialog is it that's popping up?

Comment: The one that informs you that configuration files for grub and ssh had changed and if I want to keep or replace them with the ones from the updated package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

The command should be:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
```

If you don't want to add it every time you run the command you can make the environment variable persist for your session:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

And then this works:

```
apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
```